# c:forEach in p:accordionPanel not working when item is an function with p:accordionPanel var as argument

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a code xhtml:

```
...
<p:accordionPanel var="mVar" value="#{someBean.someList}" >
    <p:tab>
        <f:facet name="title">
            <h:outputText value="#{mVar.id} - #{mVar.name}"/>
            ...
        </f:facet>
        <h:panelGrid>
            ...
            <c:forEach items="#{someBean.someFunctionReturningList(mVar.id)}" var="mImg">
                <h:outputText value="#{mImg}"/>
            </c:forEach>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
...
```

And the java code:

```
public List<String> listAllImagesForCampaign(BigInteger id) {
    List<String> allImages = new ArrayList<String>();
    ...
    return allImages;
}
```

And the problem is, that BigInteger id contains value 0, when mVar.id is 64 for example.
Is there a bug that i cant catch or sth wrong with primeface component?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

Answer (score 1):

Changing c:forEach to ui:repeat solved the problem.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{someBean.someFunctionReturningList(mVar.id)}" var="mImg">
```

Comment: Thats because c:forEach is a TagHandler and is processed before p:accordionPanel. While p:accordionPanel and ui:repeat are components. https://rogerkeays.com/jsf-c-foreach-vs-ui-repeat